# как установить одну учетную запись tunderbird на множество компьютеров?

Tags: windows, cmd, администрирование, active-directory, group-policy

Имеем компы в домене.

Появилась новая общая почта, которую нужно раскатить на 50+ пк.

Есть какой-то универсальный способ сделать это автоматически через gp/cmd?

Comment: Да. Это называется - список рассылки. Настраивается на стороне почтового сервера. Всё, что приходит туда - автоматом приезжает тем, кто состоит в подписчиках или группе. То, что хочешь - ты - классическая ошибка молотка: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/710